# Can stargazer follow booktabs style?

Tags: r, formatting, xtable, stargazer

I am quite in doubt about which table formatting package to use, being `xtable` and `stargazer`the alternatives.

I find Stargazer easier to understand when building tables - specially if a need to use **column spanning**. However, I do not know how to make stargazer tables in the `booktabs` shape. Is there a way to do so, as in `xtable`?

Alternatively, how can I use `xtable` in a way that it is easy to format spanning columns?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`stargazer-booktabs`](https://github.com/markwestcott34/stargazer-booktabs) package is a `stargazer` fork which adds support for the LaTeX `booktabs` package.

As stated on the package's webpage:

> In contrast to the main package, this fork outputs tables which use the booktabs commands `\toprule` `\midrule` and `\bottomrrule` [sic] for horizontal rules.

Again from the package's github page, it can be installed as follows:

```
install.packages("devtools")
library(devtools)

install_github("markwestcott34/stargazer-booktabs")
```

The package's [vignette](https://github.com/markwestcott34/stargazer-booktabs/blob/master/vignettes/stargazer-booktabs.pdf) provides a few examples of regression tables.